# What is the most efficient way to open/act upon all of the files in a directory?

Tags: perl

I need to perform my script (a search) on all the files of a directory. Here are the methods which work. I am just asking which is best. (I need file names of form: parsedchpt31_4.txt)

Glob:

```
my $parse_corpus; #(for all options)
##glob (only if all files in same directory as script?):
my @files = glob("parsed"."*.txt");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open($parse_corpus, '<', "$file") or die $!;
     ... all my code...
}
```

Readdir with while and conditions:

```
##readdir:
my $dir = '.';
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    next unless (-f "$dir/$file"); ##Ensure it's a file
    next unless ($file =~ m/^parsed.*\.txt/); ##Ensure it's a parsed file
    open($parse_corpus, '<', "$file") or die "Couldn't open directory $!";
     ... all my code...
}
```

Readdir with foreach and grep:

```
##readdir+grep:
my $dir = '.';
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;    
foreach my $file (grep {/^parsed.*\.txt/} readdir (DIR)) {
    next unless (-f "$dir/$file"); ##Ensure it's a file
    open($parse_corpus, '<', "$file") or die "Couldn't open directory $!";
    ... all my code...
}
```

File::Find:

```
##File::Find
my $dir = "."; ##current directory: could be (include quotes): '/Users/jon/Desktop/...'
my @files;
find(\&open_file, $dir); ##built in function
sub open_file {
    push @files, $File::Find::name if(/^parsed.*\.txt/);
}
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open($parse_corpus, '<', "$file") or die $!;
     ...all my code...
}
```

Is there another way? Is it good to enclose my entire script in the loops? Is it okay I don't use closedir? I'm passing this off to others, I'm not sure where their files will be (may not be able to use glob)

Thanks a lot, hopefully this is the right place to ask this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best or most efficient approach depends on your purposes and the larger context. Do you mean best in terms of raw speed, simplicity of the code, or something else? I'm skeptical that memory considerations should drive this choice. How many files are in the directory?

For sheer practicality, the `glob` approach works fairly well. Before resorting to anything more involved, I'd ask whether there is a problem.

If you're able to use other modules, another approach is to let someone else worry about the grubby details:

```
use File::Util qw();
my $fu = File::Util->new;
my @files = $fu->list_dir($dir, qw(--with-paths --files-only));
```

Note that `File::Find` performs a recursive search descending into all subdirectories. Many times you don't want or need that.

I would also add that I dislike your two `readdir` examples because they comingle different pieces of functionality: (1) getting file names, and (2) processing individual files. I would keep those jobs separate.

```
my $dir = '.';
opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die $!; # Use a lexical directory handle.
my @files = 
    grep { -f }
    map  { "$dir/$_" }
    grep { /^parsed.*\.txt$/ }
    readdir($dh);

for my $file (@files){
    ...
}
```

Comment: The directory isn't big(~100 files match). It was more for interest, since I researched all the different methods. Didn't find the File::Util though... The File::Find was for any other users of the code/completeness.

Why is it bad that they comingle? Readability or functionality? does for have the same effect as while (as per TLP's answer)

Comment: @Jon Comingling is bad because it contradicts one of the bedrock principles of good software design -- namely, *modularity* or *separation of concerns*. If you follow such principles, your programs will be more readable, maintainable, testable, and adaptable. It's difficult to do justice to the topic in a short comment, but it's very important.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a `while` loop is the safer answer. Why? Because loading all the file names into an array could mean a large memory usage, and using line-by-line operation avoids that problem.

I prefer `readdir` to `glob`, but that's probably more a matter of taste.

If performance is an issue, one could say that the `-f` check is unnecessary for any file with the `.txt` extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would `grep` or `next unless` be better for the while loop?

Comment: `grep` is used with arrays, so it would not be applicable. `grep` and `foreach` all load the file names into a list, which may be a bad thing if you have a large amount of files.

Comment: I think he's being prudent with the `-f` check. Not all operating systems enforce filename extensions, which means on a Unix/Linux/Mac system a directory could very well have a `.txt` extension.

Comment: @Barry Yes, I know. That's why I said "one could say".

Answer (score 1):

I find that a recursive directory walking function using the perfect partners `opendir`/[`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) and [`File::chdir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3achdir) (my fav CPAN module, great for cross-platform) allows one to easily and clearly manipulate anything in a directory including subdirectories if desired (if not, omit the recursion).

Example (a simple deep `ls`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::chdir; #Provides special variable $CWD
# assign $CWD sets working directory
# can be local to a block
# evaluates/stringifies to absolute path
# other great features

walk_dir(shift);

sub do_something {
  print shift . "\n";
}

sub walk_dir {
  my $dir = shift;
  local $CWD = $dir;
  opendir my $dh, $CWD; # lexical opendir, so no closedir needed
  print "In: $CWD\n";

  while (my $entry = readdir $dh) {
    next if ($entry =~ /^\.+$/);
    # other exclusion tests    

    if (-d $entry) {
      walk_dir($entry);
    } elsif (-f $entry) {
      do_something($entry);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Cool, hadn't heard of this module yet. It seems very flexible! My one question is, I now have to incorporate the Perl script into a CGI script, and when loading the page, it is VERY slow, will any of these be faster??

Comment: Your problem is CGI itself. Each time a page is requested a new `perl` instance is needed. This startup time is the major delay. Try a FastCGI or Mod_perl deployment or the newer Plack systems to avoid that huge overhead.

Comment: Since my post answers the question asked I am going to leave it unaltered. I put a script together that runs in a Perl environment that doesn't exit after each evaluation. You will need the `Continuity` module (which provides the stateful server). https://gist.github.com/1024315#