# How Can I get a handle to files in a dir and its subdirs?

Tags: perl

So, I recently noticed a use of opendir in a script, and would like to change it slightly so that it returns files in the subfolders of a directory as well as files in the directory itself. After investigating, I haven't been able to find any sort of recursive option for opendir, and have had trouble getting glob to return a scalar. So, rather than fudge around with either one more, I figured it would be more prudent to just ask: what is the standard way to get a handle to all files in a dir and its subdirs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classic way is with [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html), which has the advantage of being a core module, but it can be a bit of a pain. If you're able to use a third-party module, [File::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aUtil) is quite handy:

```
use File::Util;
my $fu = File::Util->new;

my $root = 'foo/bar';

my @dirs_and_files = $fu->list_dir($root, '--recurse');
my @files_only     = $fu->list_dir($root, '--recurse', '--files-only');
```

Answer (score 5):

find2perl produces example code for recursive calls over all files in a directory tree.

```
> find2perl . -type f -print
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted;



# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '.');
exit;


sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&
    print("$name\n");
}
```

Use it as a template as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In truth there's probably a module on CPAN for this, but I'd just do the recursion myself:

```
use File::Spec;

sub find($) {
    opendir my $dh, $_[0] or die;
    return
        map { $_, -d $_ ? find($_) : () }
        map { /\A\.\.?\z/ ? () : File::Spec->catfile($_[0], $_) } readdir $dh;
}
```

This includes directories in the results -- if you want *only* files, replace the first `map()` call with `map { -d $_ ? find($_) : $_ }`.

The only things you need to remember are that the path so far needs to be prepended to `readdir()`, and that it returns `.` and `..` so these need to be eliminated -- the second `map()` call (which is applied first) does both these things.  If you know the OS you're running on, you can just interpolate a `/` or `\` instead of calling `File::Spec->catfile()`, but the latter is good for portability.

Comment: @ysth: Do you mean an "infinite" directory structure via recursive symlinks/hardlinks?  Sure, but won't processing such a hierarchy fool every tool, including `find`?  To avoid being fooled, you'd need to record every seen file's inode (or equivalent), implying O(n) memory requirements just to scan n files.

Comment: no, just O(maxdepth).  find and File::Find both detect infinite cycles.  File::Find by default also excludes duplicate linked files, requiring O(n) memory, but has the option not to.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, whenever I see `File::Spec` I mention using `File::chdir` (http://p3rl.org/File::chdir). Much easier!

Comment: @ysth: Thanks, sure enough `man find` mentions that it's even a POSIX requirement.  And you're right that you only need to record O(maxdepth) inodes.  (Which can technically be O(n) for a "single chain of directories", but I realise that's not a common scenario.)  Have to say I think the Right Thing is for the OS to check for and ban hardlinked cycles, and for programs that process directory hierarchies to either always-follow (in which case, caveat emptor) or never-follow symlinks.

Comment: @Joel: I like the idea of lexically scoped current directories.  It feels very much like RAII in C++ -- you can't forget to undo a change.  Not sure it's the best fit here though as we want full pathnames anyway.

Comment: yeah, rereading your code, I guess it doesn't really help. I read your last paragraph too quickly and jumped to conclusions. Still I like to promote good modules.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have uploaded this basic structure to CPAN as [`File::chdir::WalkDir`](http://p3rl.org/File::chdir::WalkDir) ([should be live soon](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/File::chdir::WalkDir)), which exports a `walkdir` which is similar to the one shown below.

Quoted from [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324634/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-open-act-upon-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory/6338531#6338531):

I find that a recursive directory walking function using the perfect partners `opendir`/[`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) and [`File::chdir`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::chdir) (my fav CPAN module, great for cross-platform) allows one to easily and clearly manipulate anything in a directory including subdirectories if desired (if not, omit the recursion).

Example (a simple deep `ls`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::chdir; #Provides special variable $CWD
# assign $CWD sets working directory
# can be local to a block
# evaluates/stringifies to absolute path
# other great features

walk_dir(shift);

sub do_something {
  print shift . "\n";
}

sub walk_dir {
  my $dir = shift;
  local $CWD = $dir;
  opendir my $dh, $CWD; # lexical opendir, so no closedir needed
  print "In: $CWD\n";

  while (my $entry = readdir $dh) {
    next if ($entry =~ /^\.+$/);
    # other exclusion tests    

    if (-d $entry) {
      walk_dir($entry);
    } elsif (-f $entry) {
      do_something($entry);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You seem to be unaware of [File::Next](http://p3rl.org/File::Next) and [Path::Class](http://p3rl.org/Path::Class).

Comment: @daxim: Path::Class looks nice.  File::Next looks like it might not handle Windows pathnames properly (based on the existence of `reslash()`).

Comment: @Joel: I see File::chdir doesn't allow changing volumes (`C:` etc.) on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: @daxim, hadn't heard of them. I'll take a look.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, you're right, but can't you change the working dir to the new volume and go from there?

Comment: @Joel: My understanding was that you can't do that using File::chdir, because if you could then... it would not be called out as "unsupported" in the docs!  If you mean that you could change the volume outside of File::chdir (e.g. with regular `chdir()`) and use File::chdir within that volume, then technically yes you could, but you lose most of File::chdir's benefits.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, the second method was what I was asking about. Haven't used windows since before my Perl days, so thanks for clearing that up for me.